# How to have running total of asp:Labels using JavaScript in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am currently using this JavaScript to have a running total of textboxes that display to a asp:label.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Iterate through each Textbox and add keyup event handler
    $(".myTextBox0").each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            //Initialize total to 0
            var total = 0;
            $(".myTextBox0").each(function () {
                // Sum only if the text entered is number and greater than 0                             
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) { total += parseFloat(this.value); }
            });
            //Assign the total to 
            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places  
            $('#<%=lblJobTotals0.ClientID %>').html(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
});
```

How do I do the same for all the summed labels to sum themselves to a grand total of all the summed labels (to another label) ?

per David's suggestion I have tried with the only result being the lblTotalsAll changed to "0".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Iterate through each Labels
    var total = 0;
    // all labels to sum have cssClass = .lblTotals
    $(".lblTotals").each(function () {
        // add to the total  
          var labelValue = $(this).text();
        if (!isNaN(labelValue) && labelValue.length != 0) {
            total += parseFloat(labelValue);
        }

});

$('#<%=lblJobTotalsAll.ClientID %>').html(total.toFixed(2));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd start with the same concept:

```
var total = 0;
$(".myLabel0").each(function () {
    // add to the total
});
// do something with the total
```

Now, since an `asp:Label` generates a `<span>` and not an `<input>`, you can't get the value from `.value`.  Instead, you'd need to parse it from the text that you're currently writing to the element.  Something like this:

```
var labelValue = $(this).text();
if (!isNaN(labelValue) && labelValue.length != 0) {
    total += parseFloat(labelValue);
}
```

Structurally you're basically doing what you already do for the values of text boxes, but for the contents of `<span>` elements instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help @David.  I tried the following with no success.      $(document).ready(function () {
        //Iterate through each Labels
        var total = 0;
        // all labels have cssClass = .lblTotals
        $(".lblTotals").each(function () {
            // add to the total
         
                var labelValue = $(this).text();
                if (!isNaN(labelValue) && labelValue.length != 0) {
                    total += parseFloat(labelValue);
                }
             });
       $('#<%=lblJobTotalsAll.ClientID %>').html(total.toFixed(2));

        });

Comment: @AhabLives: Code in comments is nearly impossible to read.  Also, define "no success".  In what way did it fail?

Comment: I have updated the Original Question.  Hope that helps.  -Thanks.

Comment: @AhabLives: Where/how specifically does this fail?  Does `$(".lblTotals")` find any elements?  Does `$(this).text()` return the number we're looking for?  Use a debugger.

Comment: I wish I could use the debugger; however, Visual Studio 2013 Express Web and javaScript breakpoint/debugging is a nightmare(it does not skip dynamic inferred files). Regardless, thanks for the attempt it is much appreciated.

Comment: @AhabLives: Aren't you running this inside of a web browser?  Why not debug in that?  Visual Studio doesn't really have anything to do with it client-side.